# postfix does not reject forged mails

Tags: postfix, email-server

I'm running a mailserver and I want to prevent forged e-mails. As soon as an user is authenticated he can forge his e-mail.

This is the part of my `/etc/postfix/master.cf` which should contain the related config:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n - - - - smtpd
 -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
 -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
 -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
 -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
 -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
 -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
 -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-email2email.cf
 -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
 -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname
 -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
 -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

One strange thing is that no matter if I make a mistake in this config (e.g. replace `pgsql` with `foobar`) postfix seems not to care. I get no error output in `/var/log/mail.err` or `/var/log/mail.log`.

What could cause such 'errors'? Where could I search for the problems cause?

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Comment: Is this user connecting via the smtp port rather than the submission one?

Comment: Via port 587 (submission Port)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I learned... that things thunderbird displays have nothing to do with things thunderbird actually does.

After I did not have this issue with evolution it was clear it's not the client, then I blocked port 25 on serverside and then thunderbird did not send any mails (could not reach the server) - so despite configuring port 587 in the config wizard (I repeated it several times) thunderbird used port 25. Only a deletion of the thunderbird-config (~/.thunderbird) could fix this (I also reinstalled, but maybe deleting ~/.thunderbird would have been enough).